# Evaluate $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}} - \frac{a_n}{\sqrt[n]{n!}} \right)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

> Consider a sequence of real numbers $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$ such that
>
> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{n} = l > 0$$
>
> Evaluate:
>
> $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}} - \frac{a_n}{\sqrt[n]{n!}} \right)$$

*My attempt:* From Cesaro-Stolz:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_n}{n^2} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{2n+1} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{n} \cdot \frac{n}{2n+1}\right) = \frac{l}{2}$$

so intuitively $a_n \sim \dfrac{n^2\cdot l}{2}$ and thus

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}} \sim \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{(n+1)^2 \cdot l}{\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}} \sim \frac{e \cdot l}{2} \cdot (n+1)$$

which means the answer should be $\dfrac{e\cdot l}{2}$. However, I couldn't find a way to factor the difference into computable limits.

Comment: Solutions on AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h257647p1404559,  https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h345848p1850117 – found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bn%5Cto%20%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7Ba_%7Bn%2B1%7D%7D%7B%5Csqrt%5Bn%2B1%5D%7B(n%2B1)!%7D%7D%20-%20%5Cfrac%7Ba_n%7D%7B%5Csqrt%5Bn%5D%7Bn!%7D%7D%20%5Cright)%24&p=1)

Comment: @MartinR, thanks